# Appending to go lang slice using reflection

Tags: go, reflection

For some reason, it appears that adding new element to slice using reflection doesn't update slice itself. This is the code to demonstrate:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func appendToSlice(arrPtr interface{}) {
    valuePtr := reflect.ValueOf(arrPtr)
    value := valuePtr.Elem()
    value = reflect.Append(value, reflect.ValueOf(55))

    fmt.Println(value.Len()) // prints 1
}

func main() {
    arr := []int{}
    appendToSlice(&arr)
    fmt.Println(len(arr)) // prints 0
}
```

Playground link : https://play.golang.org/p/j3532H_mUL

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`reflect.Append` works like `append` in that it returns a new slice value.

You are assigning this value to the `value` variable in the `appendToSlice` function, which replaces the previous `reflect.Value`, but does not update the original argument.

To make it more clear what's happening, take the equivalent function to your example without reflection:

```
func appendToSlice(arrPtr *[]int) {
    value := *arrPtr
    value = append(value, 55)
    fmt.Println(len(value))
}
```

What you need to use is the `Value.Set` method to update the original value:

```
func appendToSlice(arrPtr interface{}) {
    valuePtr := reflect.ValueOf(arrPtr)
    value := valuePtr.Elem()

    value.Set(reflect.Append(value, reflect.ValueOf(55)))

    fmt.Println(value.Len())
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Nhabg31Sju

Answer (score 3):

```
    package main

    import "fmt"
    import "reflect"

    type Foo struct {
        Name string
    }

    func main() {
        _type := []Foo{}

        fmt.Printf("_type: v(%v) T(%T)\n", _type, _type)

        reflection := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(reflect.TypeOf(_type).Elem()), 0, 0)

        reflectionValue := reflect.New(reflection.Type())
        reflectionValue.Elem().Set(reflection)

        slicePtr := reflect.ValueOf(reflectionValue.Interface())

        sliceValuePtr := slicePtr.Elem()

        sliceValuePtr.Set(reflect.Append(sliceValuePtr, reflect.ValueOf(Foo{"a"})))
        sliceValuePtr.Set(reflect.Append(sliceValuePtr, reflect.ValueOf(Foo{"b"})))
        sliceValuePtr.Set(reflect.Append(sliceValuePtr, reflect.ValueOf(Foo{"c"})))

        values := []Foo{Foo{"d"}, Foo{"e"}}

        for _, val := range values {
            sliceValuePtr.Set(reflect.Append(sliceValuePtr, reflect.ValueOf(val)))
        }

        result := sliceValuePtr.Interface()

        fmt.Printf("result: %T = (%v)\n", result, result)
    }
```

take a look at: https://play.golang.org/p/vXOqTVSEleO