# Appending to go lang slice using reflection AND a dynamic type

Tags: go, dynamic

My question is somewhat of a follow-up to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54909356 (Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/vXOqTVSEleO).

In that answer, there's a given struct (`Foo`). I found the concept interesting and wondered the same could be done for a dynamic type.

Given the following dynamic struct (which works perfectly), how could you create a slice and append to it?

See my attempt here:

In this snippet, I create the dynamic type. This works fine.

```
        typeString := reflect.TypeOf("")
        typeInteger := reflect.TypeOf(0)
        fields := make(map[string]*reflect.StructField)
        fields["A"] = &reflect.StructField{
                Name: "A",
                Type: typeString,
                Tag:  reflect.StructTag(`json:"a"`),
        }
        fields["B"] = &reflect.StructField{
                Name: "B",
                Type: typeInteger,
                Tag:  reflect.StructTag(`json:"b"`),
        }
        var structFields []reflect.StructField
        for _, v := range fields {
                structFields = append(structFields, *v)
        }

        structType := reflect.StructOf(structFields)
```

Using the struct, we see it works fine:

```
        v := reflect.New(structType)
        v.Elem().FieldByName("A").SetString("qwer")
        v.Elem().FieldByName("B").SetInt(123)

        v2 := reflect.New(structType)
        v2.Elem().FieldByName("A").SetString("asdf")
        v2.Elem().FieldByName("B").SetInt(456)

        //+ these look good
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", v)
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", v2)
```

However, progressing into the dynamic slice, we get an error:

```
        reflection := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(reflect.TypeOf(structType).Elem()), 0, 0)

        reflectionValue := reflect.New(reflection.Type())
        reflectionValue.Elem().Set(reflection)

        slicePtr := reflect.ValueOf(reflectionValue.Interface())

        sliceValuePtr := slicePtr.Elem()

        value := v.Elem()

        // ERROR HERE
        toSet := reflect.Append(sliceValuePtr, value)
```

What needs to be adjusted to get everything to line up and `Append`?

See the following on the Playground:

https://play.golang.org/p/Vrx7FTlVBp9

Answer (score 2):

The value `structType` is a `reflect.Type`.  The expression `reflect.TypeOf(structType)` evaluates the `reflect.Type` for `reflect.Type`.  Use `structType` directly instead of calling `reflect.TypeOf(structType)` .

```
typeString := reflect.TypeOf("")
typeInteger := reflect.TypeOf(0)
fields := make(map[string]*reflect.StructField)
fields["A"] = &reflect.StructField{
    Name: "A",
    Type: typeString,
    Tag:  reflect.StructTag(`json:"a"`),
}
fields["B"] = &reflect.StructField{
    Name: "B",
    Type: typeInteger,
    Tag:  reflect.StructTag(`json:"b"`),
}
var structFields []reflect.StructField
for _, v := range fields {
    structFields = append(structFields, *v)
}

structType := reflect.StructOf(structFields)

v := reflect.New(structType)
v.Elem().FieldByName("A").SetString("qwer")
v.Elem().FieldByName("B").SetInt(123)

v2 := reflect.New(structType)
v2.Elem().FieldByName("A").SetString("asdf")
v2.Elem().FieldByName("B").SetInt(456)

//+ these look good
fmt.Printf("%v\n", v)
fmt.Printf("%v\n", v2)

reflection := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(structType), 0, 0)

fmt.Printf("typeof structType: %v\n", structType)
fmt.Printf("typeof structType | elem: %v\n", reflect.TypeOf(structType).Elem())

reflectionValue := reflect.New(reflection.Type())
reflectionValue.Elem().Set(reflection)

slicePtr := reflect.ValueOf(reflectionValue.Interface())

sliceValuePtr := slicePtr.Elem()

value := v.Elem()

fmt.Printf("value: %T = (%v)\n", value, value)
fmt.Printf("slice: %T = (%v)\n", sliceValuePtr, sliceValuePtr)

toSet := reflect.Append(sliceValuePtr, value)
fmt.Printf("toSet: %T = (%v)\n", toSet, toSet)

sliceValuePtr.Set(toSet)

result := sliceValuePtr.Interface()

fmt.Printf("result: %T = (%v)\n", result, result)
```

[Run it on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uxy9DnV_vNb).

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
stringType := reflect.TypeOf("")
intType := reflect.TypeOf(0)
t := reflect.StructOf([]reflect.StructField{
    {
        Name: "A",
        Type: stringType,
        Tag:  reflect.StructTag(`json:"a"`),
    },
    {
        Name: "B",
        Type: intType,
        Tag:  reflect.StructTag(`json:"b"`),
    },
})

v1 := reflect.New(t).Elem()
v1.FieldByName("A").SetString("qwer")
v1.FieldByName("B").SetInt(123)

v2 := reflect.New(t).Elem()
v2.FieldByName("A").SetString("asdf")
v2.FieldByName("B").SetInt(456)

slice := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(t), 0, 0)
slice = reflect.Append(slice, v1, v2)
fmt.Printf("result: %s = (%v)\n", slice.Type(), slice)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/I1M-P6IQ10S).

Answer (score 1):

As you know `reflect.TypeOf` returns a `reflect.Type` representation **of the type of the value passed to it**. So if you have a value, like `structType`, whose type *is* `reflect.Type` and you pass that to `reflect.TypeOf`, the returned `reflect.Type` will be the representation of `reflect.Type` and **not** of the type represented by the `structType` value.

Keep it simple.

```
slice := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(structType), 0, 0)
slice = reflect.Append(slice, v.Elem())
slice = reflect.Append(slice, v2.Elem())
```

https://play.golang.org/p/p_3TI0gdvHl